# UICollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath returns nil after scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have an issue with UICollectionView. The below code is to return get the cell at a point (CGPoint)

```
CollectionViewCell* cell = (CollectionViewCell*) [mCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:       [mCollectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:point]];
if (cell)
     NSLog(@"Cell exists");
else
     NSLog(@"Cell doesn't exist");
```

This returns a valid cell if the UICollectionView is left still. If it is scrolled downwards, it returns nil. I am not sure what's the issue. UICollectionView scrolling works fine. No issues with the collectionview cells.

Could some one help me out here, please?

Comment: see the documentation of [`cellForItemAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/cellForItemAtIndexPath:): "The cell object at the corresponding index path or nil if the cell is not visible or indexPath is out of range."

Comment: I am trying to get the visible cell on my view. It returns valid index path. For example, my view allows 15 collection view cells in 5 rows in portrait mode on iPad. After some scrolling, if I try to get the index path of the middle cell, it returns 7 which is valid. But [mCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath] returns nil.

Comment: Check the `indexPath` that you're getting to see if it's the one you expect. Test this out before scrolling as well as after. My guess is that you're giving it a `CGPoint` relative to the wrong view. You may need to convert the point to be relative to a different view.

Answer (score 1):

Is not a issue, in UICollectionView and UITableView, the cells that no are visibles are removed from memory.

Comment: I am trying to get the underlying cell in the collection view with a point, while handling pinch gesture.

Comment: Save the indexPath of the cell. Call `[tableView reloadData]` and in cellForRowAtIndexPath DataSource method, if saved indexPath is equals to current indexPath, you do anything with the cell.

Comment: In my case, the cell under the pinch gesture needs to be identified, and do some actions with the pinch gesture. So, just saving the index path won't help me.

Answer (score 0):

If someone else has this problem. If you have been using:

```
[myCollectionView registerClass:[customCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:yourCellIdentifier];
```

inside of viewDidAppear and you have been using prototype to create cell on storyboard or using a nib file, you should **remove [registerClass:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:]**

Also, if you're looking for a good explanation on what registerCell does and how to use it check out this [link](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Overview_of_iOS_6_Collection_View_and_Flow_Layout)